# HTML CSS LAYERS

Tags: css, html

i created a page on which i tried to attain the effect of bottom aligned tool bar like the one face book has. For that i made a div with highest z-index set the position to fixed and set the bottom 0 like

```
#bar
{
 z-index  : 11;
 position : fixed;
 bottom   : 0;
 height   : 50;
 left     : 0;
 right    : 0;
}
```

it works fine but while scrolling it seems like the page takes time rendering, like the page is heavy, scrolling is smooth but the page rendering is just a little slow that produces a not so good scroll effect. Did anyone know whats up...

or did you even get me :p

Comment: Which browsers did you test this in?

Comment: Firefox & IE & Chrome...

Comment: Which browser(s) does this happen in? Are you sure it's the this element that has caused the problem (Does it not happen when it's commented out?)

Comment: all of 'em, can this be problem of the system

Comment: are you using transparency in css or graphics? Some browsers struggle to re-render transparencies that scroll.

Comment: yes, but not of the css layers themselves but i have a number of transparent PNGs that use transparencies in a very diverse fashions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Position:fixed in itself shouldn't be causing these problems.

It sounds like the browsers are just being slow in rendering your page. Is the page large or complicated? This could be caused by over complicated HTML, CSS and especially Javascript.

Try simplifying (or disabling, for JS) each one in turn.

(I'd look hard at any JS events or and CSS that uses the * selector.)

Comment: no its not like that just one page with a background a layer with a repeating background and a few images....hey if you could please check it out i ca mail it to you...

Comment: If you put the page up on the internet and add a link here I'll probably have time for a look. You'll probably get other people's ideas too. If the page has sensitive content, strip it out from the example.

Answer (score 1):

If that bottom bar is at the bottom of the HTML-code, it will be loaded (and rendered) after everything else. If the rest of the page is big (silly code, complex javascripts or giant images), this will probably make everything worse, as styles are applied more or less continously as the page loads.

Simple way to check this: Recreate the bottom-bar at a super simple page and see if you get the same effect. If so, your page is probably to big or complicated.

Or your computer is just plain slow :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a "background-attachment: fixed" rule that may also be causing similar problems. Another issue you have to be careful about is IE6 doesn't support position: fixed, so you have to do it with JavaScript - which also slows down the website.